# Create folder during application installation in android

Tags: android

Can we create a directory on the internal storage  of the device during application installation .Also after creating that  i need to copy some images and music to that directory from our res folder. Does anyone have any ideas as to create a directory at install time? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well when you bind your application , it will be an .apk file which will contain your res folder from java project , why do you need separate folder?

Comment: +1 I'd love to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: i need two folder where i can store my images, audio generated by application.First time i have some images and audio in my res folder that i need to copy to these two folder.Once application is installed user get the permission to add more images and audio to our application.that why i try to create folder for my application

Comment: An immediate solution to this is to create directories at first launch of the application. You can use shared preferences to store a boolean to know if this is the first launch!!

Comment: @varun It's not "an immediate", it's the only solution to do this.

Comment: What is the size of information you going to store in a separate folder? If it's a couple of Mb then users won't be happy to have in the internal space - consider creating them on sd card then.

Comment: thanks for the valuable replies One more question how we can copy the files from res to newly created folder

Comment: @GrAnd I thought that there could be other/better solutions to find the first launch to do stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       // creating Derectory on SD card
       File nfile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/directory name");
       nfile.mkdir();
     }
```

Comment: will this be created each time we navigate to the main activity ?

Comment: Now question remain is... This will create a folder only the first time or EACH time the app is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the directory in an ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED Broadcast Receiver, but it must be caught on other package than your installed app.