# how to change gallery view?

Tags: java, android, gallery

Hi I have created one gallery project. but I wish to created folders view gallery..I dont know how to create that kind of gallery...please post some sample full coding...

This is my current gallery view..
[image]

Expecting gallery image:

[image]

please help me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create folder during application installation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712438/create-folder-during-application-installation-in-android/5716128#5716128)
may this helps u